# weird dash looking thing due to anchor tag

Tags: html, css

There is this weird looking dash thing in the listed elements just to the right of the image, and I can't figure it out for the life of me, but it goes away when I take out the `<a>` tags.

Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: FYI, `<a>` are *inline-level* elements, they cannot contain `<div>` which are *block-level*, your markup isn't semantic. Highly recommend running your code through a validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @sweetamylase I'm trying to make a clickable link. How should I do it? I heard only `<li>` can go in a `<ul>`, but then I need the whole thing clickable...

Comment: Add `display: block;` to your anchors `.team-list-item a{ }`, change the `<div>` elements inside to use `<span>` instead. You'll have to rejig the elements either by added `display: block` or `float` to achieve the same visual layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the regular underlining of links. Specifically, it's the white space after the image tag that gets underlined.

You can add the style `text-decoration: none;` to the links to remove the underlining:

```
.team-list-item a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Alternatively you can write the `div` right after the `img` tag to remove the white space, or you can make the image a block element floating to the left:

```
.team-list.item img { float: left; }
```

However, the last two alternatives will change the layout somewhat as it reduces the space to the right of the image. On the other hand, you may want to do that, and adjust the space with a margin or padding, as that gives a more stable layout than using space characters for spacing.